# How to put Firebase data into a marquee

Tags: html, css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, marquee

In my firebase database I have a tree with string for each node.

```
informations
|----- info 1
|----- info 2
|----- info 3
```

In my html I would like show each information into a marquee, to create something like a "news feed".
I retrieve my information correctly, the problem is how to make the marquee works for each information that is in my database. 
My marquee template is (that works correctly):

```
<div class="marquee">
  <div>
    <span>Information 1</span>
    <span>Information 2</span>
  </div>
</div>

.marquee {
  height: 25px;
  width: 420px;

  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.marquee div {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  height: 30px;

  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;

  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: -100%; }
}
```

My problem is where to put the ***ngFor** that retrieves the data from my database.

one of my marquee try code:

```
   <div class="marquee" *ngFor="let d of descriptions">
      <div>
         <span >"{{d.text}}" - {{d.user}}</span>
      </div>
   </div>
```

But with this code, the marquee contains all my informations, and not only one at a time!

How can I have a marquee that show each information form my database into one single row sequentially? Like show in this example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wpBrLv

I hope I managed to explain my problem correcty!

Comment: you want to repeat the span element, so you can add the `*ngFor` inside span

Comment: @Hareesh id doesn't work into span because it's shows all my informations in one span..I want to show one piece of information at a time, as if the news headlines were shown on the news.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<div class="marquee" >
  <div>
     <span *ngFor="let d of descriptions">"{{d.text}}" - {{d.user}}</span>
  </div>
```

css

```
@keyframes marquee {
  0% { left: 100%; }
  100% { left: -100%; }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it's shows all my informations in one span..I want to show one piece of information at a time, as if the news headlines were shown on the news.